# Rename a lot of strings in object C#

Tags: c#

I have an object containing up to 100 different headers. These headers need to be renamed for a functionality on my web-app and I can't think of a better way to do it then this:

```
private List<NameObject> TransformNames(List<NameObject> oldNameObjects)
{
    var newNameObjects = new List<NameObject>();
    foreach (var names in oldNameObjects)
    {
        switch (name.Name)
        {
            case "John Doe":
                newNameObjects.Add(new NameObject() { Name = "John Smith" });
                break;
            //continue for each name
            default:
                newNameObjects.Add(new NameObject() { Name = name.Name });
                break;
        }

    }

    return newNameObjects;
}
```

I started writing this but it will take forever. Any ideas?

Comment: why do you need to do it run-time?

Comment: Use a dictionary, or a lookup table from a text file instead of the hard coding all the names.

Comment: The question is unclear. For starters, there's no code that renames anything, there's code that creates some `NamedObject` instances as a list. If you want to map one string to another, use a `Dictionary<string,string>`. A loop that creates the new objects will run in microseconds. You can use LINQ and eg `old.Where(o=>dict.ContainsKey(o.Name)).Select(o=>new NambedObject{Name=dict[o.Name}).ToList()` to get the new objects in a single LINQ query

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the ask...
`oldNameObjects.ForEach(n => newNameObjects.Add(new NameObject() { Name = n.Name } );`

Comment: The first thing I'd do is start using `IEnumerable` instead of `List`

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a `Dictionary<string, string>` rather than a `switch` for the map. At 100s of items it will be more compact in code and should perform better, especially if you do the work to ensure you only populate the dictionary *once*, either at load or via memoization/caching.

I'd also use `IEnumerable` rather than `List` (hint: you can still pass a List to a function expecting an IEnumerable):

```
private IEnumerable<NameObject> TransformNames(IEnumerable<NameObject> oldNameObjects)
{
    // you can scope this at a higher level to save effort rebuilding it on every method call
    var map = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"John Doe", "John Smith" },
        {"Other Name", "Other result" },
        ...
    };

    return oldNameObjects.Select(n => {      
       if (!map.TryGetValue(n.Name, out string newName))
       {
           newName = n.Name;
       }
       return new NameObject() { Name = newName };
    });
}
```